# canvas is blank after drawImage()

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, javafx-8

I have a drawing window that allows a user to open an image, draw on it, then save it.

I have it on a canvas, and I can create a blank canvas, draw on it, and save it with no issues. But then when I try to open that image and do:

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
File file = new File(path);
Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
gc.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

It does the same thing as before. I get a blank canvas, that image never shows up.

Did I do something wrong in the code? I know the path is correct because I can see that image in the thumbnail in other parts of the program.

### UPDATE

Here is a complete sample program

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUITest extends Application{
    
    String path = "10-9-2016-22-28.png";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600,800);
        
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        Image original = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        gc.drawImage(original, 0, 0);
        
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

It works now until I do `canvas.widthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());` and `canvas.heightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());`. Is there something wrong with binding canvas dimensions with it's parent's dimensions?

Comment: try closing the file/image

Comment: If you open it with the default operating system program it works?How you save the file? with `ImageIO`?

Comment: @Scary, what do you mean by closing the file/image?

Comment: @Go, It works when I open through the default OS program, and it works other places in my program. I save it as a .png

Comment: Can you try removing and readding the canvas from the its root? It may be a refresh problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Michael, didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Fabian. I did that and figured out my problem. At first it wasn't working just like before but then I stopped binding my canvas width and height to the root pane and it worked. I am updating my post, but now how can I bind my canvas to the root pane without it deleting everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of a `Pane` becomes non-0 when the first layout pass is executed. Before the size is `(0, 0)`. Since there is no room in a canvas of size `(0, 0)` all the content is removed. Later when the `Canvas` grows to the root's size, you do not redraw the image, therefore nothing is shown.

For this reason every time the `Canvas` is resized you need to draw the canvas content again (or at least until the size becomes non-zero).

For the same reason you need to set the prefered size of the scene at the root element, not by setting the `Canvas` size.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(600, 800);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    Image original = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));

    root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        canvas.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
        canvas.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
        gc.drawImage(original, 0, 0);
    });

    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense